# JSON object loop api

Tags: javascript, json

New to JS, and I'm trying to create a for loop to display all the 'text' from different json objects as one large paragraph. So it looks like 'Hello, and welcome to the Minute Physics tutorial on basic Rocket Science. Before we get started,I'd like to quickly announce that I'm now making these videos at the perimeter institute for theoretical physics'

```
function loadRequest() {
    var data = null;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var obj = json[i];
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = obj.text;
    }
}
}

xhttp.open("GET", "https://fakeapi.p.rapidapi.com/sample", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "fakeapi.p.rapidapi.com");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "APIKey");

xhttp.send();
  
  
}
```

JSON:

```
"[ { 'index': 0, 'start': 0.03, 'dur': 4.499, 'end': 4.529, 'text': 'Hello, and welcome to the Minute Physics tutorial on basic Rocket Science. Before we get started,' }, { 'index': 1, 'start': 4.529, 'dur': 4.17, 'end': 8.699, 'text': 'I'd like to quickly announce that I'm now making these videos at the perimeter institute for theoretical physics' },
```

Comment: what is `json.length`

Comment: `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = data.map(o => o.text).join(" ")`

Comment: @brk number of objects

Comment: @HassanImam didn't work -- TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data.map')

Comment: Your JSON is not in a correct format, you need to fix that first. Take a look as an example here
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "start": 0.03,
    "dur": 4.499,
    "end": 4.529,
    "text": "Hello, and welcome to the Minute Physics tutorial on basic Rocket Science. Before we get started,"
  }
]
verify your json format here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.newiyo&right=local.caqije

Answer (score 0):

All of the problems in the code lie within the for loop.

```
let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    const text = json[i].text;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text;
}
```

I assume that your original `var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)` was meant to be renamed to json.

Your other problem was that you were setting the html element to equal the new text every time when you should have put `+=` to add to the text instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

I could see that your JSON structure is invalid. I have corrected the structure so that the response array works as expected. Also there are some issues with the coding aswell.

Here is the corrected version. Hope this will be helpful.

```js
const responseText = '[ { "index": 0, "start": 0.03, "dur": 4.499, "end": 4.529, "text": "Hello, and welcome to the Minute Physics tutorial on basic Rocket Science. Before we get started," }, { "index": 1, "start": 4.529, "dur": 4.17, "end": 8.699, "text": "I\'d like to quickly announce that I\'m now making these videos at the perimeter institute for theoretical physics" }]';
const json = JSON.parse(responseText);
let str = '';
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    str += json[i].text;
}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```